# why number extends NumberEnum while string not extends StringEnum?

Tags: typescript

It's intuitive that `number enums` is subsets of `number` and `string enums` is subsets of `string`.

But why `number extends NumberEnum` yield `true`?

Are there some rules behind this?

```js
const enum NumberEnum {
    a = 1
}

const enum StringEnum {
    a = 'a'
}

type R1 = string extends StringEnum ? true : false; // false
type R2 = StringEnum extends string ? true : false; // true

type R3 = number extends NumberEnum ?  true : false; // true, why?
type R4 = NumberEnum extends number ?  true : false; // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgORQIzgJwKJKoDeAsAFAyUwCGMAvDAIzkC+55oksCKMAylBwBLMAHMCvUhSq0GAcmpzW7MlACeABzgwASo3oxowsfAAeUBABMI-QSPGEYAfhiDE2gFwwAZtQA2EHAA3DAA9KE+-oHk6lq6AEwGAsYOvHDmVjZG9s6uOO4wXr4BwWERbnAqsdo6AMwGhNg4ZhZg1uhYuBKoLnkFRVGl4X1wADQwAO4AFmpOMZo1ACwGGMhN3S2ZMI24uSOFkSUhwxXkQA)

Comment: This is known drawback of enums

Comment: "*It's intuitive that number enums is subsets of number and string enums is subsets of string.*" I definitely wouldn't say it's intuitive. Mixing enums with *anything* else is a very strange to begin with.

Comment: String enums are a similar Number enum concept, but have some [subtle runtime differences](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime) as documented below. In a string enum, each member has to be constant-initialized with a string literal, or with another string enum member.

Comment: In order to understand it, write this line `const x = NumberEnum` now read the error

Comment: @VLAZ You're right. My intuition on this is totally wrong.